# Custom toString(char) method displaying incorrect result

Tags: java, delimiter, tostring

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nCustomer Id: " + this.customerId +
                "\nName: " + this.customerName +
                "\nProjects: " + "\n" + getNumberedProjects();
    }

     public String toString(char delimiter) {
        final String QUOTE = "\"";
        final String EOLN = "\n";
        String output =  Integer.toString(this.customerId) + delimiter +
                         QUOTE + this.customerName + QUOTE + delimiter +
                         Integer.toString(this.customerProjects.size());

      output += EOLN + delimiter;
        for (Project project : customerProjects)
              output += EOLN + delimiter + QUOTE + project + QUOTE;
        output += EOLN;
        return output;
     }
```

It's called by that part:

```
public void store(String filename, Repository repository) {
    try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(filename)) {
        output.print(repository.toString(DELIMITER));
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAOTextImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
```

It creates a txt file which looks like that:

[image]

But this is what I am expecting:

[image]

Comment: You have to `toString` methods here. Only the first one is called by the JDK, since that's the one that override's Object's equals.

Comment: how about showing the code where you call it?

Comment: Could you defined the pattern you want ? It is clear you are calling the correct method (since no output start with "\n Customer Id ..." but your method is messy and use to many concatenation to be readable ... PS: you really show try to use `String.format` here

Comment: First of you can write: 
`String output =  this.customerId + delimiter +
                         QUOTE + this.customerName + QUOTE + delimiter +
                         this.customerProjects.size();` because if one argument in the expression is a String then all others will be converted to a String.

Comment: I put an example how the txt file should be printed. I have to store this in format shown above so I could load it from txt file to the JDK.  About the messy code...This method was essentially created my by uni tutor. Sorry for that. If it may help, I can upload whole code.

Comment: Can you upload the whole code to a pastebin or something and post the link in comments? Also try debugging the code yourself because the output does not make sense, try using some breakpoints or just simply add a System.out.println(output) at each stage to check what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find correction in toString method. lets suppose your `Project` class has three `projectId`, `projectName` and `startDate` properties.

```
     public String toString(char delimiter) {
        final String QUOTE = "\"";
        final String EOLN = "\n";
        String output =   (this.customerId) + delimiter +
                         QUOTE + this.customerName + QUOTE + delimiter +
                         Integer.toString(this.customerProjects.size());

      output += EOLN ;
        for (Project project : customerProjects){
              output += QUOTE + project.getProjectId() + QUOTE;
              output +=   delimiter + QUOTE + project.getProjectName() + QUOTE;
              output +=   delimiter + QUOTE + project.getStartDate();
        output += EOLN;
        }
        return output;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I can infer from your code and your results:

- Clearly the `toString()` method from `Project` class does not return what you expect it to return. Did you override it too? Because in this line:

  ```
  output += EOLN + delimiter + QUOTE + project + QUOTE;
  ```

  you seem to be expecting `project` to translate to something like
    `"\"" + project.getId() + "\",\"" + project.getName() + "\",\"" + project.getStart() + "\""`
  when in fact it is returning something like this:
    `"\nProject ID: " + project.getId() + " Project Name: " + project.getName() + "  Start: " + project.getStart() + "\n"`
  You'll need to override `Project#toString()` to make it return what you want.
- You seem to be using `QUOTE` instead of `EOLN` in your actual code (not the code your showing us). Because this line `output += EOLN + delimiter;` is printing this `",` and the only explanation for that is that your *actual* code is `output += QUOTE + delimiter;`. Probably a typo, just correct it.